# Disable "quick edit" only for non admin in functions.php

Tags: quick-edit

I have this in my functions.php

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
```

to remove the quick edit link in the backend when scrolling the list of published posts.

It works like a charm but it disable it even for the admin role.
Is it possible to keep it showing only for the admin while still diabling for the rest?
Thanks!

**SOLVED thanks to jfacemyer!**
This is the full code to add in functions.php

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    return $actions;
}
if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
}
```

Comment: I believe the User Role Editor plugin will let you do this. Feel free to punch me in the head if I'm wrong.

Comment: The user role plugin has made my site instable so I needed to disable it and I've added all the small pieces of code I needed in my functions.php making them available in case I want to replicate this project in the future.
Unfortunately I'm missing the quick edit removal only for non admins...

Comment: Please be careful: the solution you outlined doesn't remove "edit" from bulk actions select. In order to do it, you have to add this snippet of code `add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'remove_from_bulk_actions' ); function remove_from_bulk_actions( $actions ){ unset( $actions[ 'edit' ] ); return $actions; }`

Comment: Could someone break this down for me.  New to editing wordpress and I am a js person.  For example what if you wanted to remove edit too?  Like where did you get remove_quick_edit and add_filter from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `current_user_can` to wrap the `add_filter` call:

```
if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
} else {
    add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
}
```

`manage_options` is an Admin capability. If the current user can do it, he's an admin (on a vanilla WP installation).

See:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

and

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: It is not specifically mentioned here, but for `hierarchical` post types,you should use: `page_row_actions` see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.2/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L1408

Answer (score 13):

Here is the code if you wish to remove the Quick Edit option from Pages as well:

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    return $actions;
}
if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    add_filter('page_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
    add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in WP 4.3.1 it is possible to use role name in `current_user_can()`. So the code may now look like this:

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
  unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
  return $actions;
}
if ( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
  add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
}
```

Cleaner and more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

**Include this in your function.php**

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wc_my_custom_css');
function wc_my_custom_css() {
     echo '<style>
               .hide-if-no-js {
                  display:none !important;
               }
          </style>';
}
```

Comment: Disable and hide there is a difference.
Please edit your answer.