# wha does the following function remove from wordpress users admin area?

Tags: wp-admin

```
function remove_stuff($action){
 if(!is_super_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_theme_options')){
   unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
   return $action;
  }else{
   return $actions; 
  }
}
add_filter('page_row_actions','remove_stuff');
add_filter('page_row_actions','remove_stuff');
```

Comment: Please edit your post, ask a real question. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This removes the 'quick edit' button from the page edit dashboard for all users who cannot edit theme options (usually admins). So, quick edit is no longer available for common editors, assuming there has been no messing with default capabilities.

The two added filters are the same. One of them is probably meant to apply to the post edit dashboard and should read `add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_stuff');`

[Read more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91511/disable-quick-edit-only-for-non-admin-in-functions-php)