# Disable "Quick edit" for roles in WP dashboard

Tags: posts, post-editor

How can you disable the "quick edit" link in posts in WP dashboard for roles with following conditions:

- The "Delete" ability shall stay
- the "View" post ability shall stay
- The "Edit" ability shall be removed

I tried this code in `functions.php`:

```php
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
}
else {
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_quick_edit', 10, 1 );
}
```

But this code prevents you also from deleting the post. The DELETE link (delete to wastebasket) shall be preserved.

Then, I tried this code in `functions.php`:

```php
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
    unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    return $actions;
}
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_quick_edit', 10, 1 );
}
```

But this code enables the EDIT link.

I refer to this post:
[Disable "quick edit" only for non admin in functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91511/disable-quick-edit-only-for-non-admin-in-functions-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you need to disable "Edit" and "Quick Edit" for non-admin roles. So you can modify your code as follows

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions ) {
    unset($actions['edit']);
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    return $actions;
} 
if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,1);
}
```

Comment: you are great! That's exactly what I wanted. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: @vallespir.  If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer. It will helps others find it as resolved.